# Calculate the derivative of the following functions.

Tags: functions, derivatives

Consider the real functions:
(1)  $f(x)=y\cos(yx) + x\sin(y) + e^{x+y}$ for $y ∈ \mathbb{R}$
(2)  $g(y) = y\cos(yx) + x\sin(y) + e^{x+y}$ for $y ∈ \mathbb{R}$
(3)  $ h(z)=y\cos(yx) + x\sin(y) + e^{x+y}$ for $x, y ∈ \mathbb{R}$
$$$$
Determine: $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$, $\frac{d}{dy}g(y)$, $\frac{d}{dz}h(z).$
$$$$
I started by calculating the derivative of the first function as: $\frac{d}{dx}(y*cos(yx)) + \frac{d}{dx}x*sin(y) + \frac{d}{dx}e^{x+y}$ and I got the following result: $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=-y^2*sin(yx)+sin(y)+e^{x+y}.$ I did the same thing with the 2 other functions, where for (2) I got $\frac{d}{dx}g(y)= cos(xy)-xy*sin(xy)+x*cos(y)+e^{x+y}$ and for (3) I got $\frac{d}{dx}h(z)=0$
Can somebody tell me if this is the right way to do it, and if not can you show me how it's done.
Thanks!

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics. Use `\times` ($\times$), `\cdot` ($\cdot$) or simply use juxtaposition.

Comment: Your application of the product rule for derivatives seems incomplete.

Comment: I also computed the whole function with an online calculator and it was the same result for all of them. But anyways, would you mind showing me how would you do it?